# SSHD drive caching algorithm vs bcache/LVM

Tags: linux, lvm, bcache

I read somewhere that the algorithms used by LVM/bcache are much better than the algorithms implemented by the H-HDD/SSHD drives. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on hybrid drive type: new Seagate SSHD drives manufactured since late 2013 have far better caching than earlier models.

What is also important, bcache caching strategy is totally different than Seagate Adaptive Memory strategy, and while bcache is very fast in benchmarks, AM learns data topology and can outperform bcache in real situations, eg.:

- loading thousands of game files (textures, sounds etc.) that have been installed sequentially with the game
- reading from flat file cache (eg. by Chrome)
- processing MTA mail queue

On the other hand, if the disk is encrypted and Adaptive Memory is not able to learn, then bcache is faster.

Comment: Are these drives of the "much better" ones: HDD SEAGATE 2.5" 5400rpm 1000GB ST1000LM014 or HDD TOSHIBA 2.5" 5400rpm 1000GB MQ02ABD100H?

Comment: I don't know these models, but in general Toshiba disk won't have Seagate Adaptive Memory technology. Try 3.5'' models ST1000DX001 and ST2000DX001 (but beware of ST4000DX001, which is slower).

Comment: I probably won't be able to get a 3.5" model since I'm buying a laptop, so my choice is quite limited.

Comment: I checked ST1000LM014 for you, it was first released on Feb 1st 2013, so it probably has older version of Adaptive Memory. To be honest I don't know, if it's enough just to update disk firmware, or if it requires some changes inside disk hardware to work. So you can take a risk or not.